# Pass dependent features automatically based on other column value

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

In the following df, `X_train` input features are `avg1`, `avg2`. Each unique `name1` represents a fixed `avg1` value and same goes for `name2` and `avg2`. For training, I have done label encoding `name1` and `name2`. While predicting output `y`, I want to pass `name1` and `name2` encoded label but it will automatically input the corresponding `avg1` and `avg2` value instead of `name1` and `name2`.

Sample Dataframe:

```
name1 name2 avg1 avg2  y
0   A   D   75   5    32
1   A   D   75   5    32
2   D   L   32   7    12
3   F   C   99   8    42
4   F   C   99   8    42
5   C   A   43   6    39
6   C   A   43   6    39
7   L   R   53   3    11
8   R   F   21   2    25
9   R   F   21   2    25
```

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
name1_labels = le.fit_transform(df['name1'])
name1_mappings = {index: label for index, label in enumerate(le.classes_)}
name2_labels = le.fit_transform(df['name2'])
name2_mappings = {index: label for index, label in enumerate(le.classes_)}
```

For example, if I give input [F,C] it should pass their corresponding `avg1` and `avg2` value.

```
model.predict(sc.transform(np.array([[99,8]])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need [`sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder.html)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()
enc.fit(df[['name1', 'name2']])
df[['name1', 'name2']] = enc.transform(df[['name1', 'name2']])
```

Comment: Alright. But how do I pass their corresponding `avg1` and `avg2` value by inputting `name1` , `name2`?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you need `df = df.set_index(['name1', 'name2'])`
and then `print(df.loc[[(4.0, 5.0)]])`